# .htaccess isn't working on 1&1 hosting and is working on local

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii2

It gives `500 Internal Server Error`. I'm wondering why this code isn't working since it fine in local. I think it has something to do with 1and1 hosting.  Here is my `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/web/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>

# Deny accessing below extensions
<Files ~ "(.json|.lock|.git)">  
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>

# Deny accessing dot files
RewriteRule (^\.|/\.) - [F]
```

How can solve the problem?

Comment: Check your error logs, if you have access to them

Comment: Are you on shared hosting? You will have to talk with your host to find the root cause. If you have root access of your server, you can check your server logs. You did provide more information about your server environment, web servers etc. so there is no way anyone can provide you solution.

Comment: @KailashAghera it is Apache server and I'm on shared hosting.

Comment: Then you have to contact your hosting provider to find the root cause of the issue.